# TabbedPageRenderer is not abstract and does not override abstract method (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget

I got the following error, when adding the NuGet-package *Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources*:

> TabbedPageRenderer is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem) in OnItemSelectedListener public class TabbedPageRenderer

For resolving this, I wanted to update the package *Xamarin.Forms* but this didn't work as well.

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the following code manually to the .csproj file of the project you are currently working on:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources" Version="1.1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser" Version="1.4.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Core" Version="1.9.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material">
      <Version>1.8.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

For me, this allowed me to update Xamarin.Forms package. And after cleaning and rebuilding the project this solved it for me.